# Setting up new default Roles in jhipster

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

How can I set up default roles in jhipster ? (using angularjs and spring).

**I explain myself**

in the registration page I want to specify the role for the registred user. let's say by a checkbox or a list. (for exemple human and animal )

How can I do that in the angular controller and in spring ?

**What I can do now ?**

I added the roles I need in the database and in angular and I can specify the roles for the new registred users , only through the Admin's users management page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some work to do, to achieve that, so I will paste just the right parts with some small samples..

In general you must extend the API to become aware of a role selection, so this information can be provided explicitly. Then you change your angularJS frontend as you need.

### for the backend

a registration happens by POSTing a `ManagedUserVM` to `/api/account/register`, so the first thing is to tell `AccountResource.registerAccount(...)` to pass a set of of strings (your roles) as additional parameter to `userService.createUser`

```
@Timed
public ResponseEntity registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody ManagedUserVM managedUserVM) {

    HttpHeaders textPlainHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    ///...
                User user = userService
                    .createUser(managedUserVM.getLogin(), 
                                managedUserVM.getPassword(),
                                managedUserVM.getFirstName(), 
                                managedUserVM.getLastName(),
                                managedUserVM.getEmail().toLowerCase(), 
                                managedUserVM.getImageUrl(), 
                                managedUserVM.getLangKey(),
                                //add authorities here
                                managedUserVM.getAuthorities()
                                );

                mailService.sendActivationEmail(user);
                //...
}
```

Then in `UserService.createUser`, you apply the set and add them to the user before saving it, by adding the `Set<String> authorities` to its parameters and

```
    if (authorities != null) {
        Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        authorities.forEach(
            authority -> authorities.add(authorityRepository.findOne(authority))
        );
        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
    }
```

and this should be sufficient to pass authorities to `/api/register/` and save them. You should be aware of users forbid to register themselves with ADMIN roles, but the security consideration is up to you and not part my answer.

### apply to frontend

Knowing your API now can process also authorities, you could just pass them.

You just add some checkbox or selectbox with `ng-model="vm.registerAccount.authorities"` to `src/main/webapp/app/account/register/register.html` (if angularJS1) or
`[(ngModel)]="registerAccount.authorities" to`src/main/webapp/app/account/register/register.component.html` (if angular2).

AFAIK this should lead automatically to the angular services passing these authorities/roles to the API.

I hope my brief answer helps you to find the proper places! Feel free to ask in comments if you stuck

Comment: thanks a lot David! I already found a way to do it and it works perfectly, I don't know if it's the optimal best practice way tho. I'll post it as soon as possible.