# User roles in JHipster 4.6.2

Tags: angular, jhipster, liquibase

I am new to JHipster and Spring. I need to add two new roles to JHipster generated (Angular 4) application - ROLE_EMPLOYEE and ROLE_EMPLOYER.

I followed the instructions from the answers to this question:
[Setting up new default Roles in jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004726/setting-up-new-default-roles-in-jhipster) but afterwards I got the Validation Error from Liquibase and the new roles didn't appear anywhere. After executing the command mvnw liquibase:clearCheckSums the error still appears.

Plus StackOverflow users are mentioning adding the roles in .ts files, but there are nowhere to be found - apparently now there is a service which is responsible for taking the role names from the database.

Can anyone provide an instruction on how to add user roles in JHipster 4.6.2 and managing the Liquibase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Liquibase checksums (non) issue has been answered many times, please search SO and read Liquibase docs. Roles are loaded with User, in your ts or html you just refer to strings like ROLE_EMPLOYEE

Comment: Can it be added from the following file?
src/main/resources/config/liquibase/authorities.csv

Comment: please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436745/using-roles-in-jhipster